# file_put_contents overwrites data

Tags: php, file-put-contents

I use file_put_content to write data in file every time there is an entry in database. Instead of appending new entry it overwrites old data with new.Here is part of code which I am using.I tried with APPEND In flag but doesn't work.  `

```
  include_once(CLASS_PATH."fetch_service.php"); 
  $objfetch = new fetchService();


  $res = $objfetch->fetch_proxy("*","where account_id='".$_SESSION['account_id']."'");
  foreach($res as $result)
  {
  $proxyname=$result['proxyname'];
  $ip=$result['proxyip'];
  $proxyport=$result['port'];
  $proxyuser=$result['username'];
  $proxypwd=$result['password'];
  $proxydomain=$result['domain'];
  $account_id=$result['account_id'];


  $content2 = "";
  $content2 .= ";/*----*-------------------*----------"."\n";
  $content2 .= "; * Created On ".date("Y-m-d")."\n";
  $content2 .= "; * Adding Proxy"."\n";
  //                $content2 .= "; * By ".$_SESSION['username']."\n";
  $content2 .= "; *----*-------------------*----------"."\n\n";



  $content2 .="[$proxyname]"."\n"; //context Name//
  $content2 .="username=$proxyuser"."\n";
  $content2 .="secret=$proxypwd"."\n";
  $content2 .="fromdomain=$proxydomain"."\n";
  $content2 .="host=$ip"."\n";
  $content2 .="port='$proxyport'"."\n";


  $content2 .="canreinvite=yes"."\n";
  $content2 .="nat=force_rport,comedia"."\n";
  $content2 .="type=peer"."\n";
  $content2 .="disallow=all"."\n";
  $content2 .="allow=g729"."\n";
  $content2 .="allow=ulaw"."\n";
  $content2 .="allow=alaw"."\n";


  $file2 = 'trunk_test.conf';
  error_log("======FILE path ====$file2======");
  file_put_contents($file2, $content2, LOCK_EX);




  }

  }
  ?>      `
```

Comment: Not clear your question, explain in detail....

Comment: @KaushaMehta rather than appending new entry in  trunk_test.conf file.its overwrites previous entry and writes new.so data only for one entry.I want for all entry in db

Comment: ok, i'm going to add answer.....

Comment: you want to append new data into the file ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to append new data into the file

you should use this flag

```
// this will append the content to the end of the file, 
// and prevent anyone else writing to the file at the same time
file_put_contents($file2, $content2, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put below code after `foreach(){ //your code for getting data and put into single variable }`. Remove the same from inside foreach and remove `$content2 = "";` too.

```
$file2 = 'trunk_test.conf';
error_log("======FILE path ====$file2======");
file_put_contents($file2, $content2, LOCK_EX);
```